# How to add two moments and get the result in minute format?

Tags: angular, datetime, video, momentjs, angular-moment

I have a showtime at 7:30(f.ShowTime) and runtime for show is 1hr:45 min(this.movie.Runtime). The runtime will change based on movie.I have a button with movie timing which should be enabled only till 8:15 i.e 30 min before show ends.I have split the hours and min to different variables and I need to convert hours to min and add together which I am doing in this.showTimeStampmin but I am not getting the correct value.Pls let me know how to add showTimehours and showTimeminutes since I get concatenation of both values when I add '+' symbol.

```
orderfoodTimeStamp: any;
  showTimeStamp: any;
  showTimehours: any;
  showTimeminutes: any;
  showTimesec: any;
  showTimeStampmin: any;
  runTimehours: any;
  runTimeminutes: any;
  runTimesec: any;
  runTimeStampmin: any;
            
            this.showTimehours = moment(f.ShowTime).format("hh");
            this.showTimeminutes = moment(f.ShowTime).format("mm");
            this.showTimeStampmin = moment(this.showTimehours * 60, 
            'minutes').add(this.showTimeminutes, 'minutes').format("mm");

            this.runTimehours = moment(this.movie.Runtime).format("hh");
            this.runTimeminutes = moment(this.movie.Runtime).format("mm");
            this.runTimeStampmin = (this.runTimehours * 60) + this.runTimeminutes;

            this.orderfoodTimeStamp = (this.showTimeStampmin + this.runTimeStampmin) - 
            30;
            if ((this.showTimeStampmin) <= this.orderfoodTimeStamp) {
              f.Disabled = false;
            } else {
              f.Disabled = true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making it so hard.

Just do use `isBetween()` function like I did below:

```
const runtime = this.movie.Runtime.split(':');
const showEndTime = moment(showStartTime).add(parseInt(runtime[0]), 'hour').add(parseInt(runtime[1]), 'minute');
const enableButtonTime = showEndTime.add(-30, 'minute');

if (moment().isBetween(enableButtonTime , showEndTime )) {
  disabled = false;
} else {
  disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: showEndTime.add(-30, 'minute'); This line throws an error since moment is not used.I tried adding moment but still it doesn't work @MahdiJoon